# Unable to match two entities without a whitespace on DialogFlow

Tags: machine-learning, dialogflow-es

I'm want to dialogflow to match the next sentence:
Search C1234567

Where the letter C is inside an entity and the 123456 (always integers) caught as number, I did what I'm showing you in the image below but seems that is not working. Do you know what could be happening?

[Unable to Match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAPiW.png)
Just as a comment if I put an extra whitespace between the C and the number (123456) it works.

======================================

## **EDIT:**

I also tryting adding three new entities:

- This for the Char [Char Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTyZ8.png)
- This one for the Numbers [Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDdaS.png)
- And finally a composite entity like this [Composite Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/essZF.png)

But as you can notice there is a space between the HPSM_Objects and Numbers entities in my TicketsHPSM entity, when i try to remove it I can't save the entity, and doing it with the whitespace DialogFlow just detect the examples inserted as phrases, for example **Search C547854** is detected but it's not **Search C524**... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try and create a composite entity OR Enum entity as shown [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities). Then use this new entity to extract your C123456 all together in the parameters.

Comment: Hey Abhinav, I also tried creating Composite entities, but for example I have this entity call "Ticket" and have this entities inside: "@HPSM_Objects:HPSM_Objects @NumbersTicket:NumbersTicket" and between them there is a space so It doesn't work well, and if I remove the space i can't save the entity, any other idea?